# Heroku error "! Authentication failure"

Tags: django, heroku

I have deployed a django app on heroku and it is working fine. But I want to run the command "python manage.py makemigrations" but it is giving me authentication error.

I am using command: "heroku run python manage.py makemigrations"

I have used my credentials correctly as I am able to use "git push heroku master".

Terminal output:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
 Running `python manage.py makemigrations` attached to terminal... up, run.3514
!    Authentication error
```

Comment: Try a `heroku auth:logout`, followed by a `heroku auth:login`, it might fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks Adrian,but I am getting the error even after trying it.

Comment: Please show the actual full error message and traceback.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have added the error I am getting. I don't know where to find more logs for this error.

Comment: If you are using Heroku Posgresql, make sure you have configured your settings.py correctly. Have a look [at the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#django-settings) for more information.

Comment: Hi Burhan, I followed that tutorial word by word . I added those configurations in the settings.py file.

Comment: May I ask why you want to run "makemigrations" on Heroku?  The normal workflow is to (1) run makemigrations locally (2) commit the migration files to your repo (3) deploy to heroku (4) run "heroku run python manage.py migrate" to run the migrations on your Heroku app.  This may not solve your authentication errors, but it will at least remove an unnecessary step from your current workflow.